# unity freezes when my loop activates, and displays no error message

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, if-statement

ok, so i am making a script for my game that generates the composition of a silicate planet. it is not great code, as i am pretty new to coding, but here it is:

```
using UnityEngine;

public class silicateComposition : MonoBehaviour
{

    public GameObject noise;

    public int silicone;
    public int ironOxide;
    public int iron;
    public int oxygen;
    public int aluminium;
    public int calcium;
    public int sodium;
    public int potassium;
    public int magnesium;

    // Start is called before the first frame update
    void Start()
    {
        Debug.Log("was run");
        int seed = noise.GetComponent<mapGenerator>().seed;

        
        
            Debug.Log("go2");
            ironOxide = seed / 15;
            iron = seed / 100;
            oxygen = seed / 13;
            aluminium = seed / 132;
            calcium = seed / 104;
            sodium = seed / 115;
            potassium = seed / 193;
            magnesium = seed / 294;
            int total = iron + ironOxide + oxygen + aluminium + calcium + sodium + potassium + magnesium;

            Debug.Log(ironOxide);
            Debug.Log(iron);
            Debug.Log(oxygen);
            Debug.Log(aluminium);
            Debug.Log(calcium);
            Debug.Log(sodium);
            Debug.Log(potassium);
            Debug.Log(magnesium);
            Debug.Log(total);
        
            if (total > 85)
            {
                int t = total - 85;
                total = total - t;
                int iod = ironOxide.ToString().Length;
                int id = iron.ToString().Length;
                int od = oxygen.ToString().Length;
                int ad = aluminium.ToString().Length;
                int sd = sodium.ToString().Length;
                int pd = potassium.ToString().Length;
                int md = magnesium.ToString().Length;
                int cd = calcium.ToString().Length;

                Debug.Log(iod);

                if (iod >= 2)
                {
                    int iod2 = iod;
                    int temp = 0;
                    while (iod > 2)
                    {
                        iod = iod - 1;
                        temp = temp + 1;

                    }
                    iod = temp;
                    int tens = 1000000;
                    temp = 0;
                    
                    while (tens.ToString().Length > iod)
                    {
                        tens = tens / 10;
                    }
                    if (tens = 1)
                    {
                        tens = 10;
                    }
                    ironOxide = ironOxide / tens;
                    
                }
                

                silicone = 100 - total;
                if (silicone < 0)
                {
                    silicone = 0;
                }

            }






        }

   

    
}
```

so basically it generates a random percentage based on real life proportions and a seed. Also i have only coded the iron Oxide loop, so I can figure out how to do it before i do it with every element.

It does work, until it hits the *if total is above 85* if statement. then unity just freezes. I do not understand why, as I have poured over the code for 2 days now and I'm losing my sanity. thank you for any help.

Comment: First, please matter your brain a bit about what your "while (iod > 2)" loop does exactly. That can definitely be replaced by some additions and subtractions!

Answer (score 0):

```
while (tens.ToString().Length > iod)
```

If `iod` is 0 or less, the loop will never terminate.

Also, `if (tens = 1)` should be `if (tens == 1)`.

Comment: i dont think that worked. unity still freezes if that if statement activates.